# LG 34WP75CP-B flickering while connected by USB-C to DisplayPort 1.4

Tags: display, displayport, usb-c

I having some flickering issues connecting my laptop to an ultrawide monitor using a USB-C-DisplayPort cable (my laptop doesn't have displayport) when I set the monitor display version to 1.4. Every driver is updated: windows, BIOS and graphic card.

Here you have the laptop and the monitor:

- Razer Blade 17" (2021) | RZ09-0406
- LG 34WP75CP-B

I have tried the same cable with another laptop and the problem is the same, but with a displaport cable it works.

I'm afraid that the problem is the cable, but the DisplayPort 1.4 should be supported according to the manufacturer.

- [Silkland Cable USB C DisplayPort 1.4 2M, 8K@60Hz, 4K@144Hz/120Hz, 5K@60Hz, 2K@240Hz/144Hz, 32.4Gbps, 8K Cable Thunderbolt 4/3 a DisplayPort 1.4 para MacBook Pro 2021, Mac Mini M1, iPad Pro, XPS 15/13](https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B09M38CXZ3/)

I also have tried to decrease the bandwidth by changing to a lower resolution, but with the same outcoming.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

**Update:**

This is the issue I'm facing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVQVHbaFLXU

But the proposed solution of changing to DP 1.2 will reduce the HZ to 100 and with no HDR.